# How to style/format point markers in Plotly 3D scatterplot?

Tags: python, plotly, markers, plotly-python, scatterplot3d

I am unsure how to customize scatterplot marker styles in Plotly scatterplots.

Specifically, I have a column `predictions` that is 0 or 1 (1 represents an unexpected value) and even though I used the `symbol` parameter in px.scatter_3d to indicate the unexpected value through varying point shape (diamond for 1 and circle for 0), the difference is very subtle and I want it to be more dramatic. I was envisioning something like below (doesn't need to be exactly this), but something along the lines of the diamond shaped points have a different outline colors or an additional shape/bubble around it. How would I do this?

Additionally, I have a `set` column which can take on one of two values, set A or set B. I used the color parameter inside `px.scatter_3d` and made that equal to `set` so the points are colored according to which set it came from. While it is doing what I asked, I don't want the colors to be blue and red, but any two colors I specify. How would I be able to this (let's say I want the colors to be blue and orange instead)? Thank you so much!

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(X_combined, x='x', y='y', z='z',
                    color='set', symbol='predictions', opacity=0.7)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12,
                         line=dict(width=5,
                         color='Black')),
              selector=dict(mode='markers'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use multiple `go.Scatter3d()` statements and gather them in a list to format each and every segment or extreme values more or less exactly as you'd like. This can be a bit more demanding than using `px.scatter_3d()`, but it will give you more control. The following plot is produced by the snippet below:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# sample data
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
x, y, z = np.cos(t), np.sin(t), t

# plotly data
data=[go.Scatter3d(x=[x[2]], y=[y[2]], z=[z[2]],mode='markers', marker=dict(size=20), opacity=0.8),
      go.Scatter3d(x=[x[26]], y=[y[26]], z=[z[26]],mode='markers', marker=dict(size=30), opacity=0.3),
      go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z,mode='markers')]

fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

How you identify the different segmens, whether it be max or min values will be entirely up to you. Anyway, I hope this approach will be useful!